# Second y axis for panel data with xtline

Tags: stata

I have panel data for spreads and illiquidity for a number of countries. Now I would like to draw for each country separately a graph with time on the x-axis and the spreads and illiqudity on **two different** y-axes.

```
xtline spreads illiquidity, i(Country) t(quarter)
```

above is the command which draws me the graphs with ONE y-axis but I do not get around how to implement the second y-axis.

The general twoway syntax, such as:

```
twoway (xtline spreads, ...) (xtline illiquidity, ... yaxis(2))
```

does not apply to xtline.

Comment: Please format the code and put it in shape so that ppl can point out the error, instead of trying to guess at the code you are trying to write.

Comment: If I would have a code I would not be asking here. With the code that is not working I am simply pointing to the fact that the general syntax for twoway graphs for a second y-axis does not apply to xtline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide data that we can replicate with. Here's a toy example using the `addplot` option. See if it does what you asked for.

```
sysuse xtline1, clear
gen new_y=runiform() // second y
xtset person day
xtline calories, addplot(line new_y day, yaxis(2))
```